# Why I have rake aborted after Execute environment in bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rake

I have a problems when I try to execute task on linux. I have a rake abort after the command Execute environment, but it works on windows. This is a task to be run by cron but it doesn't work.

this is the stack trace:

```
[railsdeploy@smtliapp017 20120528200624]$ bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake    courriel:rappel RAILS_ENV=development --trace
(in /var/rails/gdl/releases/20120528200624)
** Invoke courriel:rappel (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 31, col -1: `'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:88:in `database_configuration'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:57:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/var/rails/gdl/releases/20120528200624/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support    /dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support    /dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:217:in `block in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a syntax error in your database configuration.

Comment: I have forget a space after prefetch_rows: 20